# Alexa ends session

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am developing an Alexa skill with a custom backend.

There are some intents with slots which work fine. But recently I added another intent and experienced a strange behavior. The new intent doesn't have any slots. When I open my skill manually and perform the corresponding utterance, the session is closed. The dialog is like this:

```
1) Alexa, open <SKILL>
[My launch request response]

2) Alexa, <INTENT WITH A SLOT>
[Intent response]

3) Alexa, <INTENT WITHOUT A SLOT>
[Intent response]

4) Alexa, <ANY INTENT>
[Some default response which is not from my skill]
```

Alexa seems to cancel the current session after `3)`.
I tried to add a dummy slot to the intent which is never used and not required. By that I am able to enable the auto delegation for this intent. This hack works. The session is not cancelled. But i'd like to know why this happens and if there is any switch to press to do that. Auto delegation is already turned on globally for the skill. This also happens when I use built-in intents like the *RepeatIntent*.

I also tried to set the `shouldEndSession` field in the response. Since I don't want Alexa to listen for a specific answer this even doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the error log you received while trying to trigger that particular intent

Comment: +1 - it's likely your custom code isn't handling <ANY INTENT> correctly. When your skill errors Alexa tries to handle it gracefully by giving a default response.

Comment: This is most likely because the response you sent set shouldEndSession true. However to make sure please post the response you sent or error log.